# Who deletes that memory in python?

Tags: python, c++, memory, wrapper, swig

I use SWIG for generating wrappers. Therefore I need a function which looks like

```
%inline %{
// Serializes into a string
void* SerCmd(Class *v, int *length, char *str)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream out(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << *v;
    *length = ba.size();
    str = new char[ba.size()];
    memcpy(str, ba.constData(), ba.size());
    return str;
}
%}
```

This function is called from python then but who is deleting the memory I allocate with new? Is python doing that for me or how can that be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know SWIG, but I don't see how SWIG would know that the `str` was allocated with `new[]` as opposed to `new` or even `malloc`.  So SWIG, unless there is a contract that I don't know about, wouldn't know how to delete the memory (let alone, when to delete it).

Comment: I'm going out on a limb, but maybe this will help you?  http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library.  If you use std::string instead of raw char pointers, then pass an empty std::string by reference, and populate it in your function.  At least, that's what I believe should work (remember I am no SWIG expert).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You're ignoring the value of the `str` parameter and changing it locally in a way which is not visible to the caller, then you're returning it casted to a `void*`. Anyway, check out SWIG manual sections [5.2.5](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn14) and [12.2](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Customization.html#Customization_ownership).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: std::string is not possible because the resulting char * may contain \0.

Comment: @Oktalist: Maybe I am wrong but this is because I want to use the typemap and this is the way I found to use a pointer and get it back (INOUT).

Comment: @user1760653 - You're wrong.  A std::string can contain embedded nulls perfectly fine.  `std::string s; s.append(ba.constData(), ba.size());`  I will post this as an answer if std::string can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this doesn't answer your question, I will remove it.  But according to the SWIG information found here:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library

a `std::string` can be used instead of manually allocating memory.  Given this information, this more than likely can be used.

```
%inline %{
// Serializes into a string
void SerCmd(Class *v, int *length, std::string& str)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream out(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << *v;
    *length = ba.size();
    str.clear();
    str.append(ba.constData(), ba.size());
}
%}
```

Since you noted that the `std::string` can contain NULLs, then the proper way to handle it is to use the `string::append()` function.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append

Please note item `4)` in the link above (null characters are perfectly ok).  Note that `std::string` does *not* determine its size by a null character, unlike C-strings.

Now, to get to this data, use the `string::data()` function, along with the `string::size()` function to tell you how much data you have in the string.

Comment: I did it the following way
`std::string SerCmd(Class *v, int *length)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream out(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << *v;
    std::string str;
    str.append(ba.constData(), ba.size());
    return str;
}`

because it did not work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SWIG either, but since you asked, "Is python doing that for me or how can that be achieved?"

Python garbage collection deletes stuff when it is no longer in scope i.e. no longer has anything pointing to it. However, it cannot delete stuff it is not aware of. These docs may help.

Here is the doc on how memory management works:
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html

And here are the docs to the gc module to help give you a more control of the process.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html

Comment: This is not an answer at all. "I don't know SWIG either", but OP specifically asks how SWIG handles it.

Comment: @whitebeard The GC can only delete stuff it is aware of existance because it was allocated in the Python program, it does not delete stuff that was allocated by some parallel library that isn't even written in Python.

Comment: @C.R. No, he asked "Is python doing that for me or how can that be achieved?"

Comment: @Havenard Yes, I know. It's in the docs I referenced.  I added that to my answer.

Comment: @whitebeard: And you did not answer the question "Is python doing that for me or how can that be achieved?" because you only answered how Python handles objects created through normal means, not via SWIG.